# How to test localStorage with Jest

Tags: javascript, html, unit-testing, local-storage, jestjs

Ive mocked localStorage as suggested on another threat but i cant get the tests to work i tried multiple times with no success.

This is the mock

```js
class LocalStorageMock {
  constructor() {
    this.store = {};
  }
  clear() {
    this.store = {};
  }

  getItem(key) {
    return this.store[key] || null;
  }

  setItem(key, value) {
    this.store[key] = value.toString();
  }

  removeItem(key) {
    delete this.store[key];
  }
}
```

This is the function that im trying to test.

```js
const setToLS = (target, value) => {
  localStorage.setItem(target, JSON.stringify(value));
};
const saveToLS = (target, item) => {
  let items;
  if (localStorage.getItem(target)) {
    items = utilities.addItem(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(target)), item);
  } else {
    items = utilities.addItem([], item);
  }
  setToLS(target, items);
};
```

This the test that i cant get to work.

```js
describe('utilitiesLS', () => {

  describe('saveToLS', () => {
    it('should save item to LS')', () => {
      const target = 'recipes';
      const item = { name: 'salat', ingredients: 'spinach', id: 1 };
      utilitiesLS.saveToLS(target, item)
      expect(localStorage.store).toMatch( '{"recipes": [{"id": 1, "ingredient": "spinach", "recipeName": "salat"}]}'
      )
    });
  });
});
```

And this is the error.

```js
 expect(string)[.not].toMatch(expected)

    string value must be a string.
    Received: undefined

      29 |       const item = { recipeName: 'salat', ingredients: 'spinach', id: 1 };
      30 |       utilitiesLS.saveToLS(target, item)
    > 31 |       expect(localStorage.store).toMatch( '{"recipes": [{"id": 1, "ingredient": "spinach", "recipe
Name": "salat"}]}'
         |                                  ^
      32 |       )
      33 |     });
      34 |   });
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your test.

`LocalStorageMock.store` is an object, but your test `expect(localStorage.store).toMatch( '{"reci...` is testing it to see if it's a string. This is why your test is not passing, because objects do not match strings.

To fix this you should test:

```
  expect(localStorage.store).toEqual({"recipes": [{"id": 1, "ingredient": "spinach", "recipeName": "salat"}]})
```

Noting that localStorage.store is undefined indicates that you are also not getting the constructed instance of your mock that your test is using.

n.b. If you're trying to mock local storage, consider one of the pre-built, tested and documented approaches such as: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-localstorage-mock

Comment: I tried that too and i recieve this. expect(string)[.not].toMatch(expected)

    string value must be a string.
    Received: undefined

Comment: I've updated the matcher (should be `toEqual`) for objects- are you requiring your localStorage into your tests?

Comment: Yes im,and it still returns undefined. Expected value to equal:
      {"recipes": [{"id": 1, "ingredient": "spinach", "recipeName": "salat"}]}
    Received:
      undefined

    Difference:

      Comparing two different types of values. Expected object but received undefined.

Comment: Without details of how your injecting the mock (maybe a link to the thread you're following) it's hard to know exactly what's gone wrong; although it looks like your test and your function have different instances of your mock. However there's already pre-built solutions for this problem- I've added a link to my answer.